# Multiple conditions in Twig

Tags: if-statement, twig

I'm building a template with Twig. I was wondering what the fastest/best way is to deal with an if statement with multiple conditions.

Let's say I have 3 Images with 3 possible positions. Normally I would do this:

```
{% if image1 == 'centerleft' or 'topleft' or 'bottomleft' %}
{% set model_position = 'right' %}{% else %}{% set model_position = 'left' %}
{% endif %}

{% if image2 == 'centerleft' or 'topleft' or 'bottomleft' %}
{% set model_position = 'right' %}{% else %}{% set model_position = 'left' %}
{% endif %}
```

etc....

Is there a faster/cleaner way to do this? I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
{% set model_position = image1 in ['centerleft', 'topleft', 'bottomleft'] ? 'right': 'left' %}
```

And so on...

**edit** - explanation:

I'm using [`ternary operator`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#other-operators) to get either `left` or `right` depending on the condition. `in` is `Twig`'s [`containment operator`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#containment-operator) and works like [`in_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) function in PHP

So, if `image1` is one of `centerleft`, `topleft` or `bottomleft` then `right`, else `left`

Comment: Awesome... where did you find this info? What does this piece of code exactly do? I really can't find this info in the docs.